# How to remove -journal file without compromising the database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite and a php application that runs in background. I have blocked the application using (Ctrl-c) and I just noticed that i have database.sqlite and database.sqlite-journal.

At the moment, How can I remove -journal file without compromising the database?

Thank you!

P.S. SQLite version 3.7.9

**EDIT:**

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 damiano damiano  51M  8 mar 18.15 test.sqlite2
-rw-r--r--. 1 damiano damiano 2,6K  8 mar 18.15 test.sqlite2-journal
[damiano@localhost backup]$ sqlite3 test.sqlite2
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> 
[damiano@localhost backup]$ ls -lh
-rw-r--r--. 1 damiano damiano  51M  8 mar 18.15 test.sqlite2
-rw-r--r--. 1 damiano damiano 2,6K  8 mar 18.15 test.sqlite2-journal
[damiano@localhost backup]$
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Execute this command:

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite2 vacuum
```

It will make your database as small as possible and apply possible outstanding transactions or rollbacks in `-journal` file (and remove it in process). You can actually execute any other transaction that does something (but simply connect/disconnect is NOT enough), but vacuum seems like easiest approach.

Comment: Vacuum a) may take a while to run if the DB gets big b) may require triple the DB size while running (DB, temp copy of DB, rollback journal while it rewrites original file) and c) will exclusively lock the DB, blocking access by the OP's PHP app while running

Comment: @cheetah: true. But I have provided another option as well: run any non-trivial transaction. Simple connect/disconnect is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the database (with your program or with the `sqlite3` command-line tool).
SQLite will then roll back the changes of your interrupted transaction and afterwards remove the journal.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. It seems that -journal file has not been. I always see it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me; tried select statements on the DB, didn't deal with the journal file.

Comment: For this method to work, you have to do something that will cause SQLite to do a "write" transaction.  Since you don't want to change things, you want to rollback the transaction.  A simple example: "begin; create table force_journal_cleanup (id integer primary key); rollback;"